# How can I connect to Django development server on Codenvy?

Tags: django, codenvy

I'm currently testing Django on Codenvy but I have difficulties to find out how to connect to the build-in development server of Django.

I added a server in the Workspace configuration with port 8000 and http protocole.

I added the following in the run command of Codenvy's project :

Commande line :

```
cd ${current.project.path} && python manage.py runserver
```

Preview :

```
http://${server.port.8000}
```

The run prompt provide me a url : http://nodexx.codenvy.io:xxxxx

Going to this URL print a message : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I'm very new to all of this. Do you know what is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Django dev server by default accepts connections only from localhost. In order to access it from another machine, start runserver by binding it with an IP, or `0` for the app to be accessed from everywhere.

```
python manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

The above command runs the server in 8000 port, binding the network to `0.0.0.0`, which means the app can be accessed from anywhere

Comment: Thanks, that's definitly usefull. Seems like I'm still missing something since the page load, load, load and by the end send ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: @Thib is the URL publicly accessible? Can you share it?